# Message management using eWrapper and twsCALLBACK in IBrokers

Tags: r, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibrokers

I am trying to understand IBrokers package for interactive brokers API but am finding it extremely hard to understand the use of EWrapper methods. While I do understand that reqMktData is used to get real time data, I am not sure how to use it with eWrapper. This is the first time that I am dealing with asynchronous event driven programming. I have looked at the official documentation but I can't grasp how to make it work.

As of now, I still can't figure out how to get real time data for two stocks ("AAPL" and "GOOG") and put it in 2 different csv ("AAPL.csv" and "GOOG.csv")files separately. I believe this is something very basic but I am unable to do this. Can somebody point me to some sample code/tutorial that does this and explains the working of eWraper, twsCallBack.

Also is it possible to store the incoming data for more than 1 stock in memory and use it to send orders based on a set of rules?

Comment: In Java, after you call `reqMktData`, one of the callback methods gets called for each price (at least this is how it works for historical data, I haven't time to check but it's most probably the same concept). So you should write code in that callback, to store the received data. In the case of historical data, after the last price of my request is received, a different callback (`historicalDataEnd`) gets called to signal that no more data are to be expected. Re your last sentence, I'm sure it is possible and normal, because when I request historical data I have to specify the symbol (stock).